# how can i active a function after i destroy it in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new at python tkinter and i want to build a program with tkinter.
I use for loop to control the amount it generates and i want to build another entry after destroy it . it will show the entry box but the function(print) is not working

This is the warning:
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame3.!entry"

and here is my code:

```html
import tkinter as tk

entry = []

def create_entry():        
    n = int(create_Number_entry.get())
    for i in range(n):        
        Number_label = tk.Label(div3, text = 'Report NO :')
        Number_label.pack()
        Number_entry = tk.Entry(div3, width = 20) 
        Number_entry.pack()
        entry.append(Number_entry)
        
def delete_entry():
    for widget in div3.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

def print_entry():
    for i in entry:
        print(i.get())

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('GUI test')
align_mode = 'nswe'

pad = 5
div1 = tk.Frame(root,  width=400 , height=400 , bg='white')
div2 = tk.Frame(root,  width=200 , height=200 , bg='white')
div3 = tk.Frame(root,  width=200 , height=100 , bg='white')
div4 = tk.Frame(root,  width=200 , height=100 , bg='white')

div1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=pad, pady=pad, sticky=align_mode)
div2.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=pad, pady=pad, sticky=align_mode)
div3.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=pad, pady=pad, sticky=align_mode)
div4.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=pad, pady=pad, sticky=align_mode)

create_Number_label = tk.Label(div1, text = 'How many number you want :')
create_Number_label.pack()
create_Number_entry = tk.Entry(div1, width = 20) 
create_Number_entry.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(div2, text = "create Number entry", command = create_entry)
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(div4, text = "delete", command = delete_entry)
button2.pack()
button3 = tk.Button(div4, text = "print", command = print_entry)
button3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I stuck at it few day and really want someone to help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to empty the `entry` list when you click the `delete` button.

```
import tkinter as tk

entry = []

def create_entry():
    n = int(create_Number_entry.get())
    for i in range(n):        
        Number_label = tk.Label(div3, text = 'Report NO :')
        Number_label.pack()
        Number_entry = tk.Entry(div3, width = 20) 
        Number_entry.pack()
        entry.append(Number_entry)
        
def delete_entry():
    global entry
    for widget in div3.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    entry = []

def print_entry():
    for i in entry:
        print(i.get())

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('GUI test')
align_mode = 'nswe'

pad = 5
div1 = tk.Frame(root,  width=400 , height=400 , bg='white')
div2 = tk.Frame(root,  width=200 , height=200 , bg='white')
div3 = tk.Frame(root,  width=200 , height=100 , bg='white')
div4 = tk.Frame(root,  width=200 , height=100 , bg='white')

div1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=pad, pady=pad, sticky=align_mode)
div2.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=pad, pady=pad, sticky=align_mode)
div3.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=pad, pady=pad, sticky=align_mode)
div4.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=pad, pady=pad, sticky=align_mode)

create_Number_label = tk.Label(div1, text = 'How many number you want :')
create_Number_label.pack()
create_Number_entry = tk.Entry(div1, width = 20) 
create_Number_entry.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(div2, text = "create Number entry", command = create_entry)
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(div4, text = "delete", command = delete_entry)
button2.pack()
button3 = tk.Button(div4, text = "print", command = print_entry)
button3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy the entry widgets, they are cleared from the screen. But since you added them to a list, their reference remains.

When you try `print` function, it is fetching entries from the list and the `.get` method is invoked on destroyed entries which gives you the error.

The fix. Clear the list when you destroy the entries,that way, their references in the list are also deleted.

```
def delete_entry():
    for widget in div3.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    entry.clear()
```

Comment: it totally work!, Thanks for your careful explanation, it help me a lot